# Caml Query Error with Contains-Element

Tags: error, caml-query

I have a strange problem with a CAML-Query in SharePoint 2016 when using the Contains-Element.

This is the query:

```
<View>
    <Query>
        <Where>
            <And>
                <Contains>
                    <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
                    <Value Type='Text'>te</Value>
                </Contains>
                <Neq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Lookupable'/>
                    <Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value>
                </Neq>
                <Eq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Testcriteria'/>
                    <Value Type='Number'>1</Value>
                </Eq>
            </And>
        </Where>
    </Query>
</View>
```

It looks valid to me, but when executing it via JSOM it gives me the errors in the ULS-Log, you can see below. If I remove the Contains-Element, it works fine. It also works, when I remove the "Lookupable"- and "Testcriteria"-Blocks (and the And-Element, of course).

Any ideas?

Sebastian

---

ULS-Log:

Entering Monitored Scope (VqueryEngine). Parent=SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2

OriginalPermissionMask check failed for {967862DE-F9DC-4ACC-A778-4A39C03D34A1}. Asking for 0x00000005, have 0x2000011001

OriginalPermissionMask check failed for {967862DE-F9DC-4ACC-A778-4A39C03D34A1}. Asking for 0x00000015, have 0x2000011001

PermissionMask check failed for {967862DE-F9DC-4ACC-A778-4A39C03D34A1}. Asking for 0x00000041, have 0x2000011001

Unable to execute query: Error 0x80004005

Leaving Monitored Scope: (VqueryEngine) Execution Time=3.2016; CPU Milliseconds=2; SQL Query Count=1; Parent=SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2

Der Vorgang kann nicht erfolgreich beendet werden.  Bitte versuchen Sie es erneut.

SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2: UserPrincipalName=i:0).w|s-1-5-21-1458265474-2686932499-2065888148-2620, AppPrincipalName= ,pSqlClient= ,bstrUrl=https://intranet.xyz123.com/dev ,bstrListName={22463C43-6E4B-449D-8EF9-D05DC09FB370} ,bstrViewName= ,bstrViewXml=te01 ,fSafeArrayFlags=SAFEARRAYFLAG_DATES_IN_UTC

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Der Vorgang kann nicht erfolgreich beendet werden.  Bitte versuchen Sie es erneut., StackTrace:    bei Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureListItemsData()     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.ServerStub.SPListItemCollectionServerStub.WritePropertiesAsJson(JsonWriter writer, Object target, ProxyContext proxyContext)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.WriteAsJson(JsonWriter writer, Object obj, ClientObjectQuery objectQuery, ProxyContext proxyContext)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.WriteAsJsonWithMonitoredScope(JsonWriter writer, Object value, ClientObjectQuery objectQuery, ProxyContext proxyContext, MonitoredScopeType scopeType)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.WriteQueryResults(Object obj, ClientObjectQuery objQuery)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessQuery(XmlElement xe)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessStatements(XmlNode xe)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.Process()     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestServiceImpl.ProcessQuery(Stream inputStream, IList`1 pendingDisposableContainer)     bei Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequestService.ProcessQuery(Stream inputStream)     bei SyncInvokeProcessQuery(Object , Object[] , Object[] )     bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)     bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)     bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)     bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)     bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)     bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)     bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)     bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)     bei System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OnAsyncReceiveComplete(IAsyncResult result)     bei System.Runtime.Fx.AsyncThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(IAsyncResult result)     bei System.Runtime.AsyncResult.Complete(Boolean completedSynchronously)     bei System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.AsyncQueueReader.Set(Item item)     bei System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(Item item, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)     bei System.Runtime.InputQueue`1.EnqueueAndDispatch(T item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)     bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.SingletonChannelAcceptor`3.Enqueue(QueueItemType item, Action dequeuedCallback, Boolean canDispatchOnThisThread)     bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.CompleteParseAndEnqueue(IAsyncResult result)     bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.HandleParseIncomingMessage(IAsyncResult result)     bei System.Runtime.AsyncResult.SyncContinue(IAsyncResult result)     bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginProcessInboundRequest(ReplyChannelAcceptor replyChannelAcceptor, Action dequeuedCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)     bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult`1.ProcessHttpContextAsync()     bei System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1.BeginHttpContextReceived(HttpRequestContext context, Action acceptorCallback, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)     bei System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpTransportManager.HttpContextReceived(HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult result)     bei System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.HandleRequest()     bei System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.BeginRequest()     bei System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequest(Object state)     bei System.ServiceModel.AspNetPartialTrustHelpers.PartialTrustInvoke(ContextCallback callback, Object state)     bei System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.OnBeginRequestWithFlow(Object state)     bei System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)     bei System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)     bei System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)

Leaving Monitored Scope: (EnsureListItemsData) Execution Time=5.8977; CPU Milliseconds=4; SQL Query Count=2; Parent=Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection._SerializeToJson

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"And" tag can not have more than 2 conditions. More conditions need to be nested like below. Please try this:

```
<View>
<Query>
    <Where>
        <And>
            <And>
                <Contains>
                    <FieldRef Name='Title'/>
                    <Value Type='Text'>te</Value>
                </Contains>
                <Neq>
                    <FieldRef Name='Lookupable'/>
                    <Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value>
                </Neq>
            </And>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Testcriteria'/>
                <Value Type='Number'>1</Value>
            </Eq>
        </And>
    </Where>
</Query>
```